# How to draw two lines with GIMP?

Tags: macos, gimp

With most programs the answer would be: *Same way you draw one line.* But not with GIMP. GIMP wants to start the 2nd line where the first line ended. But that's not what I want. I want two lines with two independent start points and independent two endpoints.

**Update 1:** I tried [esc], [ctrl], [alt], [cmd], double tab on [shift] — none worked.

**Update 2:** [P], mouse click, [ctrl] [Z] does do the trick. But there should be an easier way.

Comment: Press escape before starting the second line?

Comment: I tried escape.

Comment: Apparently GIMP has [some obtuse way of drawing](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-straight-lines.html) involving pressing shift (and holding it) to set the start point, dragging the mouse and then left clicking on the end point... Not sure if that is easier than what you are doing or allows you to release shift and press it again for a new line...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Gimp has not only [some obtuse way of drawing lines](https://alvinalexander.com/design/gimp-draw-straight-line-in-gimp#comment-12107) — as @Mokubai pointed out — but there are also two ways of using it: With or without drawing the initial point.

1. Move to the point where you want to start, press [shift], move to the endpoint, make a mouse click to draw the line.
2. Move to the point where you want to start, **make a mouse click to draw a point**, press [shift], move to the end point, make a mouse click to draw a line.

Only with technique 2 you can start a new line. And as always with Gimp: Once you know it's fairly simple to use.